# Calculating Offset (Motorola 68k)

Tags: assembly, 68000

I'm given a question to find the offset as such:

Assume  the  instruction  BNE  HERE  is  in  memory  location  $FF1234  and  the  label  HERE represents  the  instruction  at  address  $FF12C0.  Compute  the  offset  (displacement)  for  thisinstruction. Will the offset be stored as an 8-bit or 16-bit value by a typical assembler? Why?

I tried doing this to find the displacement:

```
FF1234 + offset = HERE = FF12C0
I tried solving for Offset which is:

 FF1234
-FF12C0
```

Which equals: 33432820?

Would this be the correct way of calulating the offset?

Comment: No, obviously if `FF1234 + offset = FF12C0` then `offset = FF12C0 - FF1234`. Also check whether 68k uses the current or the next instruction as base.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but would it be 8 bits or 16 bits?

Comment: Since the offset is `8C` and that's out of range for 8 bit signed, it's going to be 16 bits.

Comment: So what is the range of 8 Bit signed? If a value falls in that range, then it must be 8 bits? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Range is -128 to +127 decimal, and no, it doesn't **have** to be 8 bit in that case, since all of those can be represented as 16 bit too. However anything outside of that range can not be 8 bit.

Comment: Interesting, so one can actually get a negative offset, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: check out how the BNE instruction uses the offset and what PC value uses to calculate the next PC value if the jump is taken.

From http://68k.hax.com/Bcc

> Description: If the specified condition is true, program execution
>   continues at location (PC) + displacement. The PC contains the address
>   of the instruction word of the Bcc instruction plus two. The
>   displacement is a twos compliment integer that represents the relative
>   distance in bytes from the current PC to the 16-bit displacement (the
>   word immediately following the instruction) is used. If the 8-bit
>   displacement field in the instruction word is all ones ($FF), the
>   32-bit displacement (long word immediately following the instruction) is 
>   used.

So, if the `BNE` instruction is located at `$FF1234`, the value of PC used as base for the offset to be added to, is `$FF1236`.

OTOH, the PC destination value is `$FF12C0`, so `$FF1236 + offset = $FF12C0`. `offset` will be a positive value. You should have no problem figuring it out.

Regarding this other question:

> Will the offset be stored as an 8-bit or 16-bit value by a typical
>   assembler? Why?

I don't know that it means "a typical assembler". I don't know if it refers to a typical assembler for any architecture, or a typical assembler for m68k architecture. I can only guess that this refers to a "typical assembler generating m68k object code", in which case, you should be able to answer the question just by looking at the size in bits needed by the offset value and the coding options for the BNE instruction, available in the mentioned webpage:

> Instruction Format: \i3-++-4Condition,88-bit Displacement,
>
> 016-bit Displacement if 8-bit Displacement = $00,
>
> 032-bit Displacement if 8-bit Displacement = $FF,
>
> Instruction Fields (Register Shifts): Condition field -- The binary
>   code for one of the conditions listed in the table. 8-bit Displacement
>   field -- Twos complement integer specifying the number of bytes
>   between the branch instruction and the next instruction to be executed
>   if the condition is met. 16-bit Displacement field -- Used for the
>   displacement when the 8-bit displacement field contains $00. 32-bit
>   Displacement field -- Used for the displacement when the 8-bit
>   displacement field contains $FF.
>
> Note: A branch to the immediately following instruction auto-
>   matically uses the 16-bit displacement format because the 8-bit
>   displacement field contains $00 (zero offset).